# Passing variables from Model to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have variables that are created and used on my model that I need to be able to use on my controller how is that accomplished?

Edit:

Controller: http://pastebin.com/jhAwAVa6

Model: http://pastebin.com/9xXRyYAa

Comment: Your Controller should call the Model, so you just return a value to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not pass the variable from a model to controller.
You can access public variables of a model through a controller.

```
echo $this->model_name->variable_name;
```

Comment: Well the variables I need accessed on the controller is the $userID and $verifyHash variables for the email. I have included the two files. How to I make those two variables public. Even better question is do I have the coding set up on my model page so that I can make the variables public.

Comment: @jeff-davidson you just need add public variable declaration on the model/class.
<pre><code>
class Model extends IR_Model {
    public var $userID;
    public var $verifyHash;
    public function __construct(){
    }
    // your code here
}
</code></pre>

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear from your question, what exactly you want to do.

If it is about accessing model properties, the right way is using accessor methods:

```
class Model extends CI_Model{
    private $name;

    public function getName() {return $this->name; /*any other logic here*/}
    public function setName($value) {$this->name= $value; /*any other logic here*/}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Model (my_model)

```
function useful_info()
{
    $data = new stdClass();
    $q = $this->db->get('users');
    $data->users = $this->db->result();
    $data->date = date('Y-m-d');
    $data->info = array('whatever','more','anything');
    return $data;
}
```

Controller

```
function index()
{
    $info = $this->my_model->useful_info();
    foreach($info->users as $user)
    {
        echo $user->id;
    }
    echo $info->date;
    if($info->info[0] == 'whatever')
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

You don't have to create an object (it can be a string, T/F, array, etc), but you usually need to return **something** from your model and library functions. And you can access what you return by returning it to a variable `$info = $this->my_model->useful_info();`

Comment: Well the variables I need accessed on the controller is the $userID and $verifyHash variables for the email. I have included the two files. How to I make those two variables public. Even better question is do I have the coding set up on my model page so that I can make the variables public.

Comment: @sepidol had that task right: `echo $this->user_model->userID;`. Yes, your variables are setup to be available to the controller that way, but when you modify them in the Model functions, you'll need to scope them correctly `$this->userID = 'my new value';`

Comment: Huh? I have no idea what you mean? I'm confused. I put what where?